# Add checkboxfield and hidden field in template field in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I need to set column index in checkboxfield in gridview.Iam uable to set column index on hidden field as well.
Is there any way to set column index in checkboxfield?otherwise how can I add checkboxfield and hidden field in 
a template field in gridview

```
 private void BindGridcolumns()
  {
   try
   {
     DataTable dtData;DataTable copyDataTable;
     dtData = (DataTable)Session["datagrid"];
     copyDataTable = dtData.Copy();
     copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("ServicesId");
     copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("CategoryId");
     copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("Services");
     copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("Category");
     int columnindex = 2;
     Color previouscolor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e34e08");int j = 1;
     foreach (DataColumn datacol in copyDataTable.Columns)
     {
       CheckBoxField ck = new CheckBoxField();
       ck.DataField = datacol.ColumnName;
       ck.HeaderStyle.BackColor = previouscolor;
       ck.ItemStyle.Width = 10;
       ck.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
       ck.HeaderText = datacol.ColumnName.Substring(2, datacol.ColumnName.Length - 2);
       gv_services.Columns.Insert(columnindex, ck);
       columnindex++;
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');", true
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create TemplateField dynamically also. Please check this [TemplateField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn documentation. Sample is also provided to add template field dynamically to GridView. Label is used in sample code provided but you can replace that with CheckBox.